# Flutter | Ошибка в namespace build.gradle

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Когда я изменил namespace на com.nevc.nevc_services, и запуске экспортированного приложения apk на андроид, он просто вылетает. Но когда я ставлю com.example.nevc_services, все работает, applicationId у меня com.nevc.nevc_services, я пытался делать параметры полностью одинаковыми, и наоборот, не помогло.

Comment: Ради чего вы меняете `namespace`? Этот параметр задаёт пакет для автоматически генерируемых классов и дополнения к именам активностей, сервисов, ресиверов и т.д., прописанных в манифесте с сокращением. Например: `android:name".MainActivity"` при сборке у вас превратится в `android:name"com.nevc.nevc_services.MainActivity"` и будет вылет `ClassNotFoundException`. Нужно перемещать такие классы в новый пакет либо прописывать в манифесте полностью. Кроме того `R` переедет (класс, который хранит идентификаторы ресурсов) - нужно исправлять импорты везде, где он используется.

Comment: Т.е, namespace трогать не нужно вовсе? Оно автоматически все сделает что нужно, а вот applicationId уже нужно будет сменить, перед тем как опубликовать его в Play Market?

Comment: Грубо говоря, `namespace` и нужен для того, чтобы безболезненно менять `applicationId`, не меняя больше ничего в проекте. Сам `applicationId` при этом не влияет ни на что, кроме идентификации приложения устройством и магазином. Другой вопрос, что `com.example` нежелательно использовать вообще - вы должны задать свой пакет сразу при создании нового проекта. Когда уже написана куча кода, изменить его (`namespace`) будет не просто.

Comment: Хмм, у меня в vs code не спрашивает об этом